# Drupal 8: Grouping filters for views on Search-API index

Tags: search, filter, view, grouping, drupal-8

I hardly find any documentation on creating a grouped filter query inside Drupal 8 using a Search API index.

I am especially looking for a way to create grouped filters for AND/OR conditions.

This was my old D7 way

```
function mymodule_search_api_views_query_alter
(view &$view, SearchApiViewsQuery &$query) {
   ...
   $filter_and = $query->createFilter('AND');
   $filter_and->condition('field_name1', 'my_value1');
   $query->filter($filter_and);
   ...
   $filter_or = $query->createFilter('OR');
   $filter_or->condition('field_name2', 'my_value2');
   $query->filter($filter_or);
   ...
}
```

Any tips on doing this with Drupal 8 are highly appreciated, as I did not find any documentation on doing combined filters programmatically.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

For all of you looking for a way to accomplish this:

Examining with Kint debugger on $query and $views gave a lot of useful information.

One simple way could be for filter 1:

```
$query->addWhere(1,'field_name1','value1','=');
```

or for filter 2:

```
$query->addWhere(2,'field_name2',$array_of_values,'IN');
```

If you have a more elegant solution, please let me know.